What happens to a Contact if it is deleted mid-journey in SFMC?
I wanted to undertsand whether a Contact will exit from journey if it's deleted while the Contact is on a wait Period within the journey

If a contact is deleted while they are in a wait period within a journey, the contact will be removed from the journey. The Contact Delete process removes all contact information from your account, including their presence in any active journeys. Therefore, once a contact is deleted, they will no longer proceed through the journey, even if they were in a wait period at the time of deletion.
